# cakePHP 3.0 ignore entity accessors on save

Tags: mysql, timestamp, entity, accessor, cakephp-3.0

I am in the process of converting a project from 2.x to 3.x. A week into it, I am finally starting to get a grasp of the new ORM, except for...

I am not having a good time trying to do what was once easily achieved with the `afterFind` lifecycle callback in a model.

I have a `Files` table with `created` and `modified` `DATETIME` columns.  I am using cake's Timestamp behavior in my `FilesTable` class.  Everything works properly up to this point.

The trouble begins when I try to use an accessor `_getModified($modified)` in the `File` entity class to format either of the fields.  It works fine when retrieving existing records that are already in proper `DATETIME` format, but when I try to save anything new it tries to save the accessor's formatted version, not the Timestamp behavior's version, which results in `0000-00-00 00:00:00` being saved.

In short: I want the accessor ignored when inserting/updating records.

Here is my `File` entity class:

```
class File extends Entity {
    protected function _getModified($modified) {
        $today = date("m-d-y");
        $year = date("Y");
        $file_day = date("m-d-y", strtotime($modified));
        $file_year = date("Y", strtotime($modified));

        if( $today === $file_day){
            return 'Today ' . date('g:ia', strtotime($modified)); 
        } else if ($year !== $file_year) {
            return date('M j, Y', strtotime($modified));
        } else {
            return date('M j, g:ia', strtotime($modified));  
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for ANY help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider creating **virtual property** like

```php
protected function _getFormattedDate()
{
    // Move here code from _getModified
    // $modified = $this->_properties['modified']
}
```

remove your *_getModified* method and let Timestamp Behaviour to control accessors/mutators for `modified` property

[Entities > Creating Virtual Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties)

**Note**: When converting entities to JSON or arrays, you have to explicitly list virtual fields, that should be exported to result. In this case, add this to Entity Class

```php
protected $_virtual = ['formatted_date'];
```

[Entities > Exposing Virtual Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-properties)

Comment: Since this seems to serve only presentational purposes, I'd also consider handling this via helpers.

Comment: Roman's answer would  be correct except: I am pulling this data via an **AJAX** request and returning a **JSON** object with the results of a **find**.  Virtual properties cannot be used in finds.  I am looking for a way to format a field and have it exist in the results without having to loop through the results.  Again, something like we used to do with **afterFind** in 2.x.

Comment: if you expose virtual property, it should be exported to JSON result. Try to add this line to your Entity class: `protected $_virtual = ['formatted_date'];`

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!!!  Can you maybe make note of that on your answer above, just in case anyone else is confused like me?